# NG-INIT not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I have tried several ways, but for some reason, I am not able to get the init method to work on a tab application I am building.

I am pulling in JSON using http (via WordPress REST API) and had to use the 'as' syntax to get it working properly. Everything works once I click the initial tab, but I need the first tab to load on page load.

Here is the App:

```js
JS: 

var homeApp = angular.module('homeCharacters', ['ngSanitize']);
homeApp.controller('characters', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type=character").then(function(response) {
    $scope.myData = response.data;
  });
});
homeApp.filter('toTrusted', ['$sce',
  function($sce) {
    return function(text) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
HTML: 

<section class="characters" ng-app="homeCharacters" ng-controller="characters as myData">
  <div class="char_copy" ng-repeat="item in myData" ng-bind-html="item.content | toTrusted" ng-show="myData.tab === item.menu_order">
    {{ item.content }}
  </div>
  <div class="char_tabs">
    <nav>
      <ul ng-init="myData.tab = 0">
        <li ng-repeat="item in myData">
          <a href ng-click="myData.tab = item.menu_order">
            <img src="{{ item.featured_image.source }}" />
            <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
<!--end characters-->
```

I am assuming there is something simple I am missing. The menu_order content for the tab I want to init is 0. In ng-inspector under MyData it shows tab
:
0

I would appreaciate any help anyone could offer!

Comment: Did you check any errors in console?

Comment: Yes. There are no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what happening is when UI gets rendered on page, `ng-init` directive gets processed first and it evaluates `myData.tab = 0` and set `myData`'s `tab` property value to `0`. Thereafter when asynchronous API completes retrieved data gets assigned to `myData` object again which wipes out old `myData` value.

You shouldn't be using `ng-init` for this case. You should set `data` retrieved from ajax to some another property of `myData` from controller itself.

**Code**

```
homeApp.controller('characters', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.myData = { tab: 0 }; //set default tab
  $http.get("http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type=character").then(function(response) {
    $scope.myData.data = response.data;
  });
});
```

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in myData.data">
```

Comment: As a quick follow up...what would the best way to add a class to the clicked item be using this method?

Comment: @JoethaCoder you could use `ng-class={ 'class-name': expression }`